# PHP atualizar no estoque

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de pegar a quantidade utilizada e se a pessoa recebeu ou não e atualizar no mysql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html>
<title>Produtos da OS <?php echo $id; ?></title>
<script language='JavaScript'>
function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
    else{
        if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) return true;
    else  return false;
    }
}
</script>
</html>
<?php
include('config.php');
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $senha = $_POST['senha'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $resolucao = $_POST['historico'];
  $ip1 = $_POST['ip1'];
  $ip2 = $_POST['ip2'];
  $veiculo = $_POST['automovel'];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `os_ip` (`cod_ip`,`ip1`,`ip2`,`os_id`) VALUES (NULL,'".$ip1."','".$ip2."','".$id."');");
  echo "<BR><BR><BR>";
  if(empty($usuario)){
    echo ("<center><h2><font color=red>Campo usu&aacute;rio esta em branco, favor preencher!");
  } else {
    if(empty($senha)){
    echo ("<center><h2><font color=red>Campo senha esta em branco, favor preencher!");
  } else {
    if(empty($id)){
    echo ("<center><h2><font color=red>Campo n&#186; OS esta em branco, favor preencher!");
  } else {
  $tes = mysql_query("select count(*) from os where id ='$id'");
  $tes1 = mysql_result($tes,0);
  if ($tes1==1){
  $os = mysql_query("select status from os where id='$id'");
  $os1 = mysql_result($os,0);
  $us = mysql_query("select count(*) from user where user='$usuario' and user_password='$senha'");
  $use1 = mysql_result($us,0);
  if (($os1==1)or ($os1==3)) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE os SET status=3, resolucao='$resolucao'  where id = $id");
  if ($use1 == 1) {
  if (empty($veiculo)) {
    echo ("<center><h2><font color=red>Ve&iacute;culo n&atilde;o foi selecionado!");
  } else {
  $query2 = mysql_query('SELECT nome FROM automoveis where id='.$veiculo.'');
  $auto = mysql_result($query2,0);
  $clien = mysql_query('SELECT nome_cliente FROM os where id='.$id.'');
  $cliente = mysql_result($clien,0);
  $usern = mysql_query('SELECT clientes_id FROM os where id='.$id.'');
  $username = mysql_result($usern,0);
  echo "<form action='fechaos.php' method=post>
      <table border='0' align=center width=700>
        <tr>
          <td>Usu&aacute;rio: <b>". $usuario ."</b></td>
          <td>IP: ". $ip ."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>OS n&#186;: <b>". $id ."</b></td>
          <td>Ve&iacute;culo: <b>". $auto."</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cliente: <b>".$cliente."</b></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' name='id2' value=".$id ." /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
$res = mysql_query("select * from produtos ORDER BY nome ASC"); /*Executa o comando SQL, no caso para pegar todos os usuarios do sistema e retorna o valor da consulta em uma variavel ($res)  */
echo "<table border='1' align=center width=700>
        <tr>
          <td align=center width=540><b>Nome</b></td>
          <td align=center width=100><b>Valor</b></td>
          <td align=center width=30><b>Quantidade<BR>Utilizada</b></td>
          <td align=center width=30><b>Recebeu?</b></td>

        </tr>";
/*Enquanto houver dados na tabela para serem mostrados será executado tudo que esta dentro do while */
while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

/*Escreve cada linha da tabela*/
$num = $escrever['valor'];
$num1 =  number_format($num, 2, ',', '.');
$prod6 = $escrever['id'];

echo "<tr>
        <td align=center>" . $escrever['nome'] . "</td>
        <td align=center>R$ " . $num1 . "</td>
        <td align=center><input type='text' size='10' name='quant' maxlength='3' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'></td>
        <td  align=center><select size='1'>
          <option selected></option>
          <option value='p_sim'>Sim</option>
          <option value='p_nao'>Não</option>
          <option value='p_loja'>Loja</option>
          <option value='p_repo'>Reposição</option>
          </select>
          <input name='id_prod' type='hidden' value=". $escrever['id'] .">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <input type='hidden' name='produ1' value=".$prod6 ." />";
}/*Fim do while*/
echo "</table>
<table border=0 align=center>
<tr>
  <td><BR><input type='submit' value='Finalizar OS'></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>"; /*fecha a tabela apos termino de impressão das linhas*/
}
} else {
  echo "<font color=red><center>Usu&aacute;rio ou senha errados ou n&atilde;o esta autorizado!</font>";
}
} else {
  echo "<center><h1><font color=red>OS j&aacute; foi finalizada, favor informar ao Leo, para verificação!";
}
}else{
  echo ("<center><h1><font color=red>OS n&atilde;o encontrada!");
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Essa é a pag 'fechaos.php'

```
<?php
include('config.php');
  $quant = $_POST['quant'];
  $id = $_POST['id2'];
  $produto = $_POST['id_prod'];


  echo $quant, $id, $produto;
  mysql_query("UPDATE os SET status=0 where id = $id");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `estoque` (`produtos_id`,`cc`,`quant`) VALUES ('".$produto."','0','".$quant."');");
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Você quer colocar a sua tabela dentro de um form ou manipula-la com javascript?

Comment: ela esta no form com while

Comment: O que não deve estar a conseguir é ter a informação dos selects porque não têm name.

Comment: Não deve repetir names portanto aconselho que implente qualquer coisa como name="nome_$escrever[id]"

Comment: Se está a usar echo "" não precisa fazer echo "texto".$variavel."texto"; basta fazer echo "texto $variavel texto"; É a grande diferença entre "" e '' no php

Comment: Pode detalhar mais o constrangimento? Foi claro qual é o objetivo mas não especificou o constrangimento.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve gerar os names dinamicamente

Crie uma variável e incremente ela a cada iteração, assim você poderá criar campo-1, campo-2, campo-3...

ex:

```
<?php
  $i = 1;
  echo '<form>';
  while(condicao){
     echo "<input type='text' name='campo-".$i."'>";
     echo "<select name='combo-".$i."'>";
         echo "<option value='op1'>Opcao 1</option>";
         echo "<option value='op2'>Opcao 2</option>";
     echo "</select>";
     i++;
  }
  echo '</form>';
?>
```

A partir daí fica muito simples receber do outro lado

Comment: Não deveria ser $i se pretende gravar na base dados (update) mas sim id para conseguir identifica-los. Se está a usar "" na minha opniao não deveria usar ".$i." porque o php já verifica variaveis ser for ""

Comment: @TiagoGomes no caso está apenas separando os campos com identificadores numéricos sequenciais. Até o campo que receberá a ID do produto tambem seria sequenciada. A ideia é, todo campo encerrado com 1 se refere a um produto, 2 a outro produto, e assimsucessivamente. Não vai interferir no valoar a ID vai apenas simplificar e organizar o processamento da página. Assim ele poderá trabalhar como quiser, separar cada produto num array antes de salvar ou definir um array pra quantidade e outro pras opções, fica muito flexivel e fácil de trabalhar.

Comment: É apenas uma opinião. Quando existe uma base dados por trás a referencia deveria ser o id e não um numero sequencial. Para ser fácil a sua identificação. Principalmente quando na própria tabela não existe esse dado.